# Display the saved images in dropzone after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropzone.js

Now, I use dropzone to implement the image upload and same the images into collectionFS, after upload I can see the images in dropzone, but after refresh the page, there is no images display.I can get the saved images from collectionFS, but how to set the value we can display the images when the page is loaded.
according to the checking for dropzone.js file, in the following file, it will define "this.files = []; whether we can pass one savefiles as one options items to this.files? after that, it can load saved files when page is load.
function Dropzone(element, options)

Comment: Uhh, fetch them again on `activate` to display them?

Comment: not fetch them again, it means when the page is loaded first time, fetch the data and display.

Comment: Then you can store them locally or somewhere where you can get them right away on page load. `init, get, display, store locally, reload, get locally` and the succeeding page reloads will just get the data locally.

Comment: Yes, I can store them and get them. but I do not know how to display the images into dropzone, whether there is one parameter, I can pass the images into dropzone.js to display together?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dropzone.js` so I will just be general. You can create a `container` below the dropzone then display the images there. This container will not be a part of the dropzone per se.

Comment: I can understand your mean, to create a container, it is OK, I already try it, but I want to display the images in dropzone, becase, it will better to add /remove using only one component.

Comment: That would be good if `dropzone.js` supports it. In any case, I can only suggest to achieve the unavailable features manually. Let''s just hope someone familiar with it comes along.

Comment: In fact, I want to modify it, in my side I use nodejs, require dropzone in node_modules, after modify dropzone.js in node_modules, I do not know how to build this module.

Answer (score 1):

according to the following description from https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ, it can dispaly the image.

```
var mockFile = { name: image.name, size: image.size};
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, image.url());
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
```

but the size of image is not correct, it does not resize. so use the following:

```
myDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, image.url());
```

but the image can not display. 
the image is added firstly, and save it into gridfs, after that, reload the page to get image.
is there any wrong to use dropzone?****